# How to put a picture at the center of a page in landscape mode

Tags: graphics, landscape

I have a big picture that is too wide for putting in a page, so I tried the landscape mode to rotate the page. The issue is that the picture is not located at the center.

How can I make the picture to move to the center?

[image: enter code here]

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight, width=1.5\textwidth]{fig/decomp.pdf}
  \caption{Functional Decomposed Data Structure}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\begin{landscape}\centering
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight, width=1.5\textwidth]{fig/decomp.pdf}
  \caption{Functional Decomposed Data Structure}
\end{figure}
\vfill
\end{landscape}
```